# jQuery Tips and Tricks

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Syntax

- [Shorthand for the ready-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/2218129#2218129) by roosteronacid
- [Line breaks and chainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/2218135#2218135) by roosteronacid
- [Nesting filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/389474#389474) by Nathan Long
- [Cache a collection and execute commands on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/552831#552831) by roosteronacid
- [Contains selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/1519474#1519474) by roosteronacid
- [Defining properties at element creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/2750689#2750689) by roosteronacid
- [Access jQuery functions as you would an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/3967325#3967325) by roosteronacid
- [The noConflict function - Freeing up the $ variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/182666#182666) by Oli
- [Isolate the $ variable in noConflict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/382853#382853) by nickf
- [No-conflict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/2218120#2218120) by roosteronacid

### Data Storage

- [The data function - bind data to elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/382834#382834) by TenebrousX
- [HTML5 data attributes support, on steroids!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/5410587#5410587) by roosteronacid
- [The jQuery metadata plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/504776#504776) by Filip Dupanović

### Optimization

- [Optimize performance of complex selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/1019899#1019899) by roosteronacid
- [The context parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/504732#504732) by lupefiasco
- [Save and reuse searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/389793#389793) by Nathan Long
- [Creating an HTML Element and keeping a reference, Checking if an element exists, Writing your own selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/382922#382922) by Andreas Grech

### Miscellaneous

- [Check the index of an element in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/389906#389906) by redsquare
- [Live event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/892617#892617) by TM
- [Replace anonymous functions with named functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/696385#696385) by ken
- [Microsoft AJAX framework and jQuery bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/191139#191139) by Slace
- [jQuery tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/922865#922865) by egyamado
- [Remove elements from a collection and preserve chainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/998547#998547) by roosteronacid
- [Declare $this at the beginning of anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/191061#191061) by Ben
- [FireBug lite, Hotbox plug-in, tell when an image has been loaded and Google CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/1771311#1771311) by Colour Blend
- [Judicious use of third-party jQuery scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/182715#182715) by harriyott
- [The each function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/1584927#1584927) by Jan Zich
- [Form Extensions plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/1235178#1235178) by Chris S
- [Asynchronous each function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/2750689#2750689) by OneNerd
- [The jQuery template plug-in: implementing complex logic using render-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/4962433#4962433) by roosteronacid

Answer (score 252):

**Creating an HTML Element and keeping a reference**

```
var newDiv = $("<div />");

newDiv.attr("id", "myNewDiv").appendTo("body");

/* Now whenever I want to append the new div I created, 
   I can just reference it from the "newDiv" variable */
```

**Checking if an element exists**

```
if ($("#someDiv").length)
{
    // It exists...
}
```

**Writing your own selectors**

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    over100pixels: function (e)
    {
        return $(e).height() > 100;
    }
});

$(".box:over100pixels").click(function ()
{
    alert("The element you clicked is over 100 pixels height");
});
```

Comment: Writing your own selectors is pretty slick

Comment: Also, if it's any help, you can actually do $("<div/>") and achieve the same thing as $("<div></div>")

Comment: I love the new selector part, didn't know about that.

Comment: Since I can't edit community wikis yet: Combine assignment and existence check with `if ((var someDiv = $("#someDiv")).length) { /* do stuff with someDiv... */ }`

Comment: Adding selectors: amazing!   Wish I learned that a long time ago!

Comment: @Ben: The reason I avoid such idioms in JavaScript is because I don't want to give the illusion of `someDiv` having being scoped in the `if` statement, because it isn't; JavaScript only supports function scope

Answer (score 111):

jQuery's [`data()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data) method is useful and not well known. It allows you to bind data to DOM elements without modifying the DOM.

Comment: I have noticed that it doesn't work with elements without set ID.

Comment: Use data() instead of declaring global js variables, imo.

Answer (score 95):

### Nesting Filters

You can nest filters (as [nickf showed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382301/jquery-accordion-close-then-open#382828)).

```
.filter(":not(:has(.selected))")
```

Comment: Although be careful with this... :has performs a full-depth search, so it can get quite expensive.

Answer (score 80):

I'm really not a fan of the `$(document).ready(fn)` shortcut. Sure it cuts down on the code but it also cuts way down on the readability of the code. When you see `$(document).ready(...)`, you know what you're looking at. `$(...)` is used in far too many other ways to immediately make sense.

If you have multiple frameworks you can use `jQuery.noConflict();` as you say, but you can also assign a different variable for it like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j("#myDiv").hide();
```

Very useful if you have several frameworks that can be boiled down to `$x(...)`-style calls.

Comment: @Oli: About the document ready-shorthand; you have a point. But never the less: it is a tip/trick. One which I use in all my code purely because I think it "looks" better. A matter of personal preference, I guess :)

Comment: Every day I wade through pointless XML/XLS/XLST, sites written with far too many layers of abstraction, complex fail-over systems on sites that will never outgrow the humblest of servers... and still people complain about the difference between $(<string>) & $(<function>). Makes me want to cry :)

Comment: When I see $(function(){...}) I know what's going on. The more usual things should be shorter. That's why we turn frequently called code fragments into functions.

Answer (score 77):

Ooooh, let's not forget [jQuery metadata](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata)! The data() function is great, but it has to be populated via jQuery calls.

Instead of breaking W3C compliance with custom element attributes such as:

```
<input 
  name="email" 
  validation="required" 
  validate="email" 
  minLength="7" 
  maxLength="30"/>
```

Use metadata instead:

```
<input 
  name="email" 
  class="validation {validate: email, minLength: 2, maxLength: 50}" />

<script>
    jQuery('*[class=validation]').each(function () {
        var metadata = $(this).metadata();
        // etc.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: html5 data attributes make this less of an issue; there is discussion afoot on bringing html5 data attribute inline with jquery's data() function: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/patch-feedback-requested-html5-data-attrs-transcend-into-the-fn-data-api

Comment: @Oskar - yep this has been implemented in jQuery 1.4.3 -- `data-*` attributes are automatically available via calls to `.data()`

Answer (score 73):

### Live Event Handlers

Set an event handler for **any** element that matches a selector, even if it gets added to the DOM after the initial page load:

```
$('button.someClass').live('click', someFunction);
```

This allows you to load content via ajax, or add them via javascript and have the event handlers get set up properly for those elements automatically.

Likewise, to stop the live event handling:

```
$('button.someClass').die('click', someFunction);
```

These live event handlers have a few limitations compared to regular events, but they work great for the majority of cases.

For more info see the [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

**UPDATE: `live()` and `die()` are deprecated in jQuery 1.7.   See http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/ for similar replacement functionality.**

**UPDATE2: `live()` has been long deprecated, even before jQuery 1.7. For versions jQuery 1.4.2+ before 1.7 use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and `undelegate()`.** The `live()` example (`$('button.someClass').live('click', someFunction);`) can be rewritten using `delegate()` like that: `$(document).delegate('button.someClass', 'click', someFunction);`.

Comment: Yeah, I love the new live stuff. Note that it only works starting with jQuery 1.3.

Comment: +1..you have saved me alot of heart ache..I just happened to read your entry and while I was taking a break - trobleshooting why my event was not firing. Thanks

Comment: for any other late-comers to this article, you may also want to look at delegate(): http://api.jquery.com/delegate/  Similar to live, but more efficient.

Comment: Just remember .live bubbles up to the body so that the bound live event can be fired. If something along the way cancels that event, the live event will not fire.

Comment: live() and die() are deprecated methods since jQuery 1.7 released november 3rd.

Replaced by on(), http://api.jquery.com/on/ and
off(), http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 46):

Replace anonymous functions with named functions. This really supercedes the jQuery context, but it comes into play more it seems like when using jQuery, due to its reliance on callback functions. The problems I have with inline anonymous functions, are that they are harder to debug (much easier to look at a callstack with distinctly-named functions, instead 6 levels of "anonymous"), and also the fact that multiple anonymous functions within the same jQuery-chain can become unwieldy to read and/or maintain. Additionally, anonymous functions are typically not re-used; on the other hand, declaring named functions encourages me to write code that is more likely to be re-used.

An illustration; instead of:

```
$('div').toggle(
    function(){
        // do something
    },
    function(){
        // do something else
    }
);
```

I prefer:

```
function onState(){
    // do something
}

function offState(){
    // do something else
}

$('div').toggle( offState, onState );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because jQuery passes the event target as `this`, you can't get "proper" OO without using enclosures. I usually go for a compromise: `$('div').click( function(e) { return self.onClick(e) } );`

Comment: I'm sorry Ben, but I fail to see how your comment has any relevance to my post. Can you elaborate? You can still use 'self' (or any other variable) using my suggestion; it won't change any of that at all.

Comment: Yeh, Ben, what exactly do you mean!?

Comment: I must mention: always fur variable and functions in namespace not in root !!

Answer (score 45):

**Defining properties at element creation**

In jQuery 1.4 you can use an object literal to define properties when you create an element:

```
var e = $("<a />", { href: "#", class: "a-class another-class", title: "..." });
```

... You can even add styles:

```
$("<a />", {
    ...
    css: {
        color: "#FF0000",
        display: "block"
    }
});
```

Here's a [link to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Answer (score 43):

instead of using a different alias for the jQuery object (when using noConflict), I always write my jQuery code by wrapping it all in a closure. This can be done in the document.ready function:

```
var $ = someOtherFunction(); // from a different library

jQuery(function($) {
    if ($ instanceOf jQuery) {
        alert("$ is the jQuery object!");
    }
});
```

alternatively you can do it like this:

```
(function($) {
    $('...').etc()    // whatever jQuery code you want
})(jQuery);
```

I find this to be the most portable. I've been working on a site which uses both Prototype AND jQuery simultaneously and these techniques have avoided all conflicts.

Comment: The second example is nice'r for the eyes :)

Comment: There is a difference though, the first example will wait for the document.ready() event to fire, while the second won't.

Comment: @SamBeran: True, the second example will run immediately; however, if you are wrapping an object-literal, you can use $(document).ready(...) inside the object-literal which means you can specify when you'd like to run each piece of code.

Comment: `instanceOf` won't work, only `instanceof`. And it won't work anyway, because `jQuery instanceof jQuery` will return `false`. `$ == jQuery` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: Yes, you're right, but that's not really the point of the code example.

Answer (score 39):

### **Check the Index**

jQuery has .index but it is a pain to use, as you need the list of elements, and pass in the element you want the index of:

```
var index = e.g $('#ul>li').index( liDomObject );
```

The following is much easier:

If you want to know the index of an element within a set (e.g. list items) within a unordered list:

```
$("ul > li").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).prevAll().length;
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the core index() method? It's been in core since 1.2 at least.

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index

Comment: Ok, yes I was playing devil's advocate somewhat, because as I was reviewing jQuery's index() I realized it was kind of a pain in the butt. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This is cool, but important to know that it doesn't work quite right if you had previous siblings that weren't part of the selection.

Comment: I'm pretty sure since jQuery 1.4, you can just use `index()` and get the index from its parent.

Comment: @alex - sure, but note the date of this post - it was 5 months before the 1.4 release!

Answer (score 23):

**Shorthand for the ready-event**

The explicit and verbose way:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // ...
});
```

The shorthand:

```
$(function ()
{
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 22):

On the core jQuery function, specify the context parameter in addition to the selector parameter.  Specifying the context parameter allows jQuery to start from a deeper branch in the DOM, rather than from the DOM root.  Given a large enough DOM, specifying the context parameter should translate to performance gains.

Example: Finds all inputs of type radio within the first form in the document.

```
$("input:radio", document.forms[0]);
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext

Comment: A note: `$(document.forms[0]).find('input:radio')` does the same thing. If you look at the jQuery source, you'll see: if you pass a second parameter to `$`, it will actually call `.find()`.

Comment: What about... `$('form:first input:radio')`?

Comment: Paul Irish pointed out in http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/ (starting on slide 17) that doing this is "backwards" from a readability standpoint.  As @Nyuszika7H pointed out, it uses .find() internally, and $(document.forms[0]).find('input:radio') is very easy to read, compared to putting the context in the initial selector.

Answer (score 21):

Not really jQuery only but I made a nice little bridge for jQuery and MS AJAX:

```
Sys.UI.Control.prototype.j = function Sys$UI$Control$j(){
  return $('#' + this.get_id());
}
```

It's really nice if you're doing lots of ASP.NET AJAX, since jQuery is supported by MS now having a nice bridge means it's really easy to do jQuery operations:

```
$get('#myControl').j().hide();
```

So the above example isn't great, but if you're writing ASP.NET AJAX server controls, makes it easy to have jQuery inside your client-side control implementation.

Comment: Does the ajax clientside library provide a way of finding a control by the original Id you assigned (in the code behind)

Comment: this.get_id() will return you the ID of the control in the client scope. The server-specified ID is irrelivant as the client ID is generated depending on the parent cotrol hierachy

Answer (score 20):

**Optimize performance of complex selectors**

Query a subset of the DOM when using complex selectors drastically improves performance:

```
var subset = $("");

$("input[value^='']", subset);
```

Comment: Only if that subset is cached/saved.

Comment: That's not much different then $("").find("input[value^='']")

Comment: @Dykam: which it is, in the case of my example-code. But your point is still valid.

Comment: @Chad, it's actually identical and maps to the function you wrote

Answer (score 19):

Speaking of Tips and Tricks and as well some tutorials. I found these series of tutorials (**“jQuery for Absolute Beginners” Video Series)** by [Jeffery Way](http://jeffrey-way.com/) are VERY HELPFUL.

It targets those developers who are new to jQuery. He shows how to create many cool stuff with jQuery, like animation, Creating and Removing Elements and more...

I learned a lot from it. He shows how it's easy to use jQuery.
Now I love it and i can read and understand any jQuery script even if it's complex.

Here is one example I like "**Resizing Text**"

**1- jQuery...**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            var originalSize = $('p').css('font-size'); // get the font size 
            var number = parseFloat(originalSize, 10); // that method will chop off any integer from the specified variable "originalSize"
            var unitOfMeasure = originalSize.slice(-2);// store the unit of measure, Pixle or Inch

            $('p').css('font-size', number / 1.2 + unitOfMeasure);
            if(this.id == 'larger'){$('p').css('font-size', number * 1.2 + unitOfMeasure);}// figure out which element is triggered
         });        
     });
</script>
```

**2- CSS Styling...**

```
<style type="text/css" >
body{ margin-left:300px;text-align:center; width:700px; background-color:#666666;}
.box {width:500px; text-align:justify; padding:5px; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px; color:#0033FF; background-color:#FFFFCC;}
</style>
```

**2- HTML...**

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" id="larger">Larger</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="Smaller">Smaller</a>
    <p>
    In today’s video tutorial, I’ll show you how to resize text every time an associated anchor tag is clicked. We’ll be examining the “slice”, “parseFloat”, and “CSS” Javascript/jQuery methods. 
    </p>
</div>
```

Highly recommend these tutorials...

http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/

Answer (score 19):

**Asynchronous each() function**

If you have **really complex documents** where running the jquery **each()** function locks up the browser during the iteration, and/or Internet Explorer pops up the '*do you want to continue running this script*' message, this solution will save the day.

```
jQuery.forEach = function (in_array, in_pause_ms, in_callback)
{
    if (!in_array.length) return; // make sure array was sent

    var i = 0; // starting index

    bgEach(); // call the function

    function bgEach()
    {
        if (in_callback.call(in_array[i], i, in_array[i]) !== false)
        {
            i++; // move to next item

            if (i < in_array.length) setTimeout(bgEach, in_pause_ms);
        }
    }

    return in_array; // returns array
};


jQuery.fn.forEach = function (in_callback, in_optional_pause_ms)
{
    if (!in_optional_pause_ms) in_optional_pause_ms = 10; // default

    return jQuery.forEach(this, in_optional_pause_ms, in_callback); // run it
};
```

**The first way you can use it is just like each():**

```
$('your_selector').forEach( function() {} );
```

An **optional 2nd parameter lets you specify the speed/delay in between iterations** which may be useful for animations (*the following example will wait 1 second in between iterations*):

```
$('your_selector').forEach( function() {}, 1000 );
```

Remember that since this works asynchronously, you can't rely on the iterations to be complete before the next line of code, for example:

```
$('your_selector').forEach( function() {}, 500 );
// next lines of code will run before above code is complete
```

I wrote this for an internal project, and while I am sure it can be improved, it worked for what we needed, so hope some of you find it useful. Thanks -

Answer (score 18):

Syntactic shorthand-sugar-thing--Cache an object collection and execute commands on one line:

**Instead of:**

```
var jQueryCollection = $("");

jQueryCollection.command().command();
```

**I do:**

```
var jQueryCollection = $("").command().command();
```

A somewhat "real" use case could be something along these lines:

```
var cache = $("#container div.usehovereffect").mouseover(function ()
{
    cache.removeClass("hover").filter(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: it better to put the $(this) reference in a local variable, because you wil take a minor perfomance hit here, because it will take a little longer...

Comment: In this case (no pun intended) I am only using "this" one time. No need for caching.

Comment: A small tip.  While it may not matter in this case it's always a bad idea to make extra changes to the DOM.  Say for example the element you are hovering over already had the class "hover".  You would be removing this class and re-adding it.  You can get around that with `$(this).siblings().removeClass("hover")`.  I know this sounds like such a small thing but every time you change the DOM another browser redraw may be triggered.  Other possibilities include events attached to DOMAttrModified or the classes changing the height of the element which could fire other "resize" event listeners.

Comment: If you want to use the cache and minimize DOM changes you can do this. `cache.not(this).removeClass("hover")`

Comment: @gradbot: I don't understand your last two comments. Could you expand?

Answer (score 15):

I like declare a `$this` variable at the beginning of anonymous functions, so I know I can reference a jQueried this.

Like so:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // Other code
});
```

Comment: ROA: Yeah, that'll be the acid :)

You can also use arguments.callee to enable an anonymous function to reference itself

Comment: Joe - just a heads up, callee will be going away with ECMAScript 5 and strict mode. See: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Comment: @Joe You could give it a name, just be wary of [IE's quirks](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs).

Comment: Great example also of using a $ at the beginning of the variable name to indicate a jQuery object variable as compared to a standard variable.  By adding that to the beginning of any variable that is caching a jQuery object, you immediately know by looking at it that you can perform jQuery functions on the variable.  Makes the code much more readable immediately.

Answer (score 14):

### Save jQuery Objects in Variables for Reuse

Saving a jQuery object to a variable lets you reuse it without having to search back through the DOM to find it.

(As @Louis suggested, I now use $ to indicate that a variable holds a jQuery object.)

```
// Bad: searching the DOM multiple times for the same elements
$('div.foo').each...
$('div.foo').each...

// Better: saving that search for re-use
var $foos = $('div.foo');
$foos.each...
$foos.each...
```

As a more complex example, say you've got a list of foods in a store, and you want to show only the ones that match a user's criteria. You have a form with checkboxes, each one containing a criteria. The checkboxes have names like `organic` and `lowfat`, and the products have corresponding classes - `.organic`, etc.

```
var $allFoods, $matchingFoods;
$allFoods = $('div.food');
```

Now you can keep working with that jQuery object. Every time a checkbox is clicked (to check or uncheck), start from the master list of foods and filter down based on the checked boxes:

```
// Whenever a checkbox in the form is clicked (to check or uncheck)...
$someForm.find('input:checkbox').click(function(){

  // Start out assuming all foods should be showing
  // (in case a checkbox was just unchecked)
  var $matchingFoods = $allFoods;

  // Go through all the checked boxes and keep only the foods with
  // a matching class 
  this.closest('form').find("input:checked").each(function() {  
     $matchingFoods = $matchingFoods.filter("." + $(this).attr("name")); 
  });

  // Hide any foods that don't match the criteria
  $allFoods.not($matchingFoods).hide();
});
```

Comment: My naming convention is to have a `$` in front. e.g. `var $allItems = ...`

Comment: @Lavinski - I think the idea is that the `$` indicates that this is a jQuery object, which would make it easier to visually differentiate from other variables.

Comment: @Louis - I have since adopted your convention, and will update my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 11):

It seems that most of the interesting and important tips have been already mentioned, so this one is just a little addition.

The little tip is the [jQuery.each(object, callback)](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) function. Everybody is probably using the [jQuery.each(callback)](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) function to iterate over the jQuery object itself because it is natural. The jQuery.each(object, callback) utility function iterates over objects and arrays. For a long time, I somehow did not see what it could be for apart from a different syntax (I don’t mind writing all fashioned loops), and I’m a bit ashamed that I realized its main strength only recently.

The thing is that since the **body of the loop in jQuery.each(object, callback) is a function**, you get a **new scope** every time in the loop which is especially convenient when you create **closures** in the loop.

In other words, a typical common mistake is to do something like:

```
var functions = [];
var someArray = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    functions.push(function() { alert(someArray[i]) });
}
```

Now, when you invoke the functions in the `functions` array, you will get three times alert with the content `undefined` which is most likely not what you wanted. The problem is that there is just one variable `i`, and all three closures refer to it. When the loop finishes, the final value of `i` is 3, and `someArrary[3]` is `undefined`. You could work around it by calling another function which would create the closure for you. Or you use the jQuery utility which it will basically do it for you:

```
var functions = [];
var someArray = [1, 2, 3];
$.each(someArray, function(item) {
    functions.push(function() { alert(item) });
});
```

Now, when you invoke the functions you get three alerts with the content 1, 2 and 3 as expected.

In general, it is nothing you could not do yourself, but it’s nice to have.

Answer (score 11):

**Access jQuery functions as you would an array**

Add/remove a class based on a boolean...

```
function changeState(b)
{
    $("selector")[b ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("name of the class");
}
```

Is the shorter version of...

```
function changeState(b)
{
    if (b)
    {
        $("selector").addClass("name of the class");
    }
    else
    {
        $("selector").removeClass("name of the class");
    }
}
```

Not that many use-cases for this. Never the less; I think it's neat :)

**Update**

Just in case you are not the comment-reading-type, ThiefMaster points out that the [toggleClass accepts a boolean value](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), which determines if a class should be added or removed. So as far as my example code above goes, this would be the best approach...

```
$('selector').toggleClass('name_of_the_class', true/false);
```

Comment: This is neat, and has some interesting uses, but it isn't anything specific to jQuery at all... this is just something you can do on any JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks :) ... It's basic JavaScript; yeah. But I would argue that jQuery is JavaScript. I'm not claiming that this is jQuery-specific.

Comment: In this specific case you really want to use `$('selector').toggleClass('name_of_the_class', b);` though.

Answer (score 9):

**Remove elements from a collection and preserve chainability**

Consider the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

```
$("li").filter(function()
{
    var text = $(this).text();

    // return true: keep current element in the collection
    if (text === "One" || text === "Two") return true;

    // return false: remove current element from the collection
    return false;
}).each(function ()
{
    // this will alert: "One" and "Two"       
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

The `filter()` function removes elements from the jQuery object. In this case: All li-elements not containing the text "One" or "Two" will be removed.

Comment: Isn't it simpler just to use "each" and move the margin change inside the switch?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please let me know if I'm making myself clear(er)

Comment: Does this really REMOVE li elements?  It seems to alert with a filtered list of elements.

Comment: The filter function removes elements from the collection inside the jQuery object. It does not affect the DOM.

Comment: In your filter function, you can simply write: return !!$(this).text().match(/One|Two/);
;)

Answer (score 9):

Update:

Just include this script on the site and you’ll get a Firebug console that pops up for debugging in any browser. Not quite as full featured but it’s still pretty helpful! Remember to remove it when you are done.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'></script>
```

Check out this link:

[From CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/use-firebug-in-any-browser/)

Update:
I found something new; its the the JQuery Hotbox.

[JQuery Hotbox](http://www.s3maphor3.org/demo/hotbox/)

Google hosts several JavaScript libraries on Google Code. Loading it from there saves bandwidth and it loads quick cos it has already been cached.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

    // Load jQuery  
    google.load("jquery", "1.2.6");  

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {  
        // Your code goes here.  
    });  

</script>
```

Or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also use this to tell when an image is fully loaded.

```
$('#myImage').attr('src', 'image.jpg').load(function() {  
    alert('Image Loaded');  
});
```

The "console.info" of firebug, which you can use to dump messages and variables to the screen without having to use alert boxes. "console.time" allows you to easily set up a timer to wrap a bunch of code and see how long it takes.

```
console.time('create list');

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var myList = $('.myList');
    myList.append('This is list item ' + i);
}

console.timeEnd('create list');
```

Comment: ppl in Iran can't see web pages loaded with google api. in fact google has restrict Iranians to access google code. so -1

Comment: I just found out you can use firebug in any browser. That's awesome.

Answer (score 9):

Use filtering methods over pseudo selectors when possible so jQuery can use querySelectorAll (which is much faster than sizzle). Consider this selector:

```
$('.class:first')
```

The same selection can be made using:

```
$('.class').eq(0)
```

Which is must faster because the initial selection of '.class' is QSA compatible

Comment: @Nyuszika7H I think you're missing the point. The point is that QSA can't optimize most pseudo selectors, thus $('.class:eq(0)') would be slower than $('.class').eq(0).

Answer (score 8):

**Changing the type of an input element**

I ran into this issue when I was trying to change the type of an input element already attached to the DOM. You have to clone the existing element, insert it before the old element, and then delete the old element. Otherwise it doesn't work:

```
var oldButton = jQuery("#Submit");
var newButton = oldButton.clone();

newButton.attr("type", "button");
newButton.attr("id", "newSubmit");
newButton.insertBefore(oldButton);
oldButton.remove();
newButton.attr("id", "Submit");
```

Answer (score 7):

Judicious use of third-party jQuery scripts, such as form field validation or url parsing. It's worth seeing what's about so you'll know when you next encounter a JavaScript requirement.

Answer (score 7):

**Line-breaks and chainability**

When chaining multiple calls on collections...

```
$("a").hide().addClass().fadeIn().hide();
```

You can increase readability with linebreaks. Like this:

```
$("a")
.hide()
.addClass()
.fadeIn()
.hide();
```

Comment: In this case, the first is more readable, but yeah, there are some cases when line breaks increase readibility.

Answer (score 7):

Use .stop(true,true) when triggering an animation prevents it from repeating the animation. This is especially helpful for rollover animations.

```
$("#someElement").hover(function(){
    $("div.desc", this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
},function(){
    $("div.desc", this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Using self-executing anonymous functions in a method call such as `.append()` to iterate through something. I.E.:

```
$("<ul>").append((function ()
{
    var data = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
        output = $("<div>"),
        x = -1,
        y = data.length;

    while (++x < y) output.append("<li>" + info[x] + "</li>");

    return output.children();
}()));
```

I use this to iterate through things that would be large and uncomfortable to break out of my chaining to build.

Answer (score 5):

This one goes out to [Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi).

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
// hide all elements which contains the text "abc"
$("p").each(function ()
{
    var that = $(this);

    if (that.text().indexOf("abc") > -1) that.hide();
});
```

Here's a shorthand... which is about twice as fast:

```
$("p.value:contains('abc')").hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

**HTML5 data attributes support, on steroids!**

The [data function](http://api.jquery.com/data/) has been mentioned before. With it, you are able to associate data with DOM elements.

Recently the jQuery team has added support for [HTML5 custom data-* attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). And as if that wasn't enough; they've force-fed the data function with steroids, which means that you are able to store complex objects in the form of JSON, directly in your markup.

The HTML:

```
<p data-xyz = '{"str": "hi there", "int": 2, "obj": { "arr": [1, 2, 3] } }' />
```

The JavaScript:

```
var data = $("p").data("xyz");

data.str // "hi there"
typeof data.str // "string"

data.int + 2 // 4
typeof data.int // "number"

data.obj.arr.join(" + ") + " = 6" // "1 + 2 + 3 = 6"
typeof data.obj.arr // "object" ... Gobbles! Errrghh!
```

Answer (score 3):

### Add a selector for elements above the fold

#### As a jQuery selector plugin

```
 $.extend($.expr[':'], {
 "aboveFold": function(a, i, m) {
   var container = m[3],
   var fold;
  if (typeof container === "undefined") {
     fold = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
  } else {
     if ($(container).length == 0 || $(container).offset().top == null) return false;
     fold = $(container).offset().top + $(container).height();
  }
  return fold >= $(a).offset().top;
 } 
});
```

#### Usage:

```
$("p:aboveFold").css({color:"red"});
```

Thx to [scottymac](http://flowcoder.com/scottymac)

Answer (score 1):

*(This is a shamless plug)*

Instead of writing repetitive form handling code, you can try out [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-extensions/) I wrote that adds to the fluent API of jQuery by adding form related methods:

```
// elementExists is also added
if ($("#someid").elementExists())
  alert("found it");

// Select box related
$("#mydropdown").isDropDownList();

// Can be any of the items from a list of radio boxes - it will use the name
$("#randomradioboxitem").isRadioBox("myvalue");
$("#radioboxitem").isSelected("myvalue");

// The value of the item selected. For multiple selects it's the first value
$("#radioboxitem").selectedValue();

// Various, others include password, hidden. Buttons also
$("#mytextbox").isTextBox();
$("#mycheck").isCheckBox();
$("#multi-select").isSelected("one", "two", "three");

// Returns the 'type' property or 'select-one' 'select-multiple'
var fieldType = $("#someid").formElementType();
```

Comment: you know about .length and .is() (api.jquery.com/is), right? if( $('#whatever').length) { /* present */ }, $('#myDropDown').is('select')... wow. wow, wow, wow, wow (and don't forget about $.fn.val ...)

Comment: Yes I do @Dan, the plugin is based on design by contract. `is` doesn't determine if it's a textbox, hidden field etc. either. The whole point of the plugin is easy to read functions that test easily (which is why it comes with about 15 test using qunit)

Answer (score 1):

On a more fundamental and high-level note, you could try to emulate the basic selector mechanism of jQuery by writing your own little framework (it's simpler than it sounds). Not only will it improve your Javascript no end, it will also help you to understand just why jQuery's $("#elementId") is many times faster than $(".elementClass") and is also faster than $("element#elementId") (which is perhaps on the surface counter-intuitive).

This will also force you to learn about object oriented Javascript which will help you to organise your code in a more modular fashion, thereby avoiding the spaghetti code nature that heavy jQuery script blocks can take on.

Answer (score 1):

**Access iFrame Elements**
Iframes aren’t the best solution to most problems, but when you do need to use one it’s very handy to know how to access the elements inside it with Javascript. jQuery’s contents() method makes this a breeze, enabling us to load the iframe’s DOM in one line like this:

```
$(function(){
    var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#someID").contents();
    //Now you can use <strong>find()</strong> to access any element in the iframe:

    iFrameDOM.find(".message").slideUp();
    //Slides up all elements classed 'message' in the iframe
});
```

[source](http://www.problogdesign.com/coding/30-pro-jquery-tips-tricks-and-strategies/)

Answer (score 1):

The "ends with" element selector is great for ASP.NET web forms development because you don't need to worry about the prepended ctl00 silliness:

```
$("[id$='txtFirstName']");
```

As noted in the comments, this selector (as with any layer of abstraction) can be slow if used without care.  Prefer to scope the selector to some containing element, e.g.,

```
$(".container [id$='txtFirstName']");
```

to reduce the number of required elements to traverse.

[jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue)

Comment: You should probably note/warn that this type of selector is incredibly slow. Unless you're selecting on a subset, or a cached collection, this selector will traverse all elements in the DOM and run a regular expression on the ID property to determine a match.

Comment: Stephen when it really bad, you can use this one, it searches entire id
$("input[id*=txtFirstName]"); //* search "all"

Most of the time I use ClientID
$('#<%=txtFirstName.ClientId %>');

Answer (score 0):

**No-conflict mode**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

> "Run this function to give control of the `$` variable back to whichever library first implemented it. This helps to make sure that jQuery doesn't conflict with the `$` object of other libraries.
>
> By using this function, you will only be able to access jQuery using the `jQuery` variable. For example, where you used to do `$("div p")`, you now must do `jQuery("div p")`".

Answer (score 0):

### Increment Row Index in name

Here is a neat way to increment a row index of a cloned input element if your input element name contains a row index like `'0_row'`:

```
$(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/^\d+/, function(n){ return ++n; }));
```

The cloned element's name will now be `'1_row'`

Answer (score 0):

A shameless plug... [The jQuery template plug-in: implementing complex logic using render-functions](http://roosteronacid.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/10/the-jquery-template-plug-in-implementing-complex-logic-using-render-functions/)

> The new jQuery template plug-in is
>   awesome. That being said, the
>   double-curly brace template-tags are
>   not exactly my cup of tea. In a more
>   complex template the tags obscure the
>   templates markup, and implementing
>   logic past simple if/else statements
>   is a pain.
>
> After messing around with the plug-in
>   for a few hours, my head began to hurt
>   from trying to distinguish the markup
>   in my template from the millions of
>   double curly braces.
>
> So I popped an aspirin and began work
>   on an alternative

Comment: Look at JSRender.  I think the double-curly brace seems to be becoming a bit of a standard for templates in JavaScript templating.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to an event and execute the event handler immediately:

```
$('selector').bind('change now', function () { // bind to two events: 'change' and 'now'
    // update other portions of the UI
}).trigger('now'); // 'now' is a custom event
```

This is like

```
function update() {
    // update other portions of the UI
}
$('selector').change(update);
update();
```

but without the need to create a separate named function.