# jQuery.map - Practical uses for the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a better understanding of the [jQuery.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) function.

So in general terms .map takes a array and "maps" it to another array of items.

easy example:

```
$.map([0,1,2], function(n){
    return n+4;
});
```

results in [4,5,6]

I think I understand what it does.  I want to under why would someone need it.  What is the practical use of this function?  How are you using this in your code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$.map` is all about converting items in a set.

As far as the DOM, I often use it to quickly pluck out values from my elements:

```
var usernames = $('#user-list li label').map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
})
```

The above converts the `<label>` elements inside a list of users to just the text contained therein. Then I can do:

```
alert('The following users are still logged in: ' + usernames.join(', '));
```

Comment: [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) are different functions. You are referring to `$.map` and the example provided is of `.map()`

Comment: The code provided in the example won't work as is because you first need to convert the mapped list into a native array using .get(). Here is the corrected code:  
  
    var usernames = $('#user-list li label').map(function() {
        return this.innerHTML;
    }).get();

Answer (score 36):

Mapping has two main purposes: grabbing properties from an array of items, and converting each item into something else.

Suppose you have an array of objects representing users:

```
var users = [
  { id: 1, name: "RedWolves" },
  { id: 2, name: "Ron DeVera" },
  { id: 3, name: "Jon Skeet" }
];
```

Mapping is a convenient way to grab a certain property from each item. For instance, you can convert it into an array of user IDs:

```
var userIds = $.map(users, function(u) { return u.id; });
```

As another example, say you have a collection of elements:

```
var ths = $('table tr th');
```

If you want to store the contents of those table headers for later use, you can get an array of their HTML contents:

```
var contents = $.map(ths, function(th) { return th.html(); });
```

Comment: Cool. You should add tips to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks

Answer (score 6):

Map is a [high-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)), that enables you to apply certain function to a given sequence, generating a new resulting sequence containing the values of each original element with the value of the applied function.

I often use it to get a valid selector of all my jQuery UI panels for example:

```
var myPanels = $('a').map(function() { 
  return this.hash || null; 
}).get().join(',');
```

That will return a comma separated string of the panels available in the current page like this:

```
"#home,#publish,#request,#contact"
```

And that is a valid selector that can be used:

```
$(myPanels);// do something with all the panels
```

Comment: That's a nice use case!

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
$.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {     
    return { value: item.tagName, data: item.id };
})
```

Here server will be returning the "response" in JSON format, by using `$.parseJSON` it is converting JSON object to Javascript Object array.

By using `$.map` for each object value it will call the `function(item)` to display the result  value: `item.tagName, data: item.id`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing you could use it for.

```
$.map(["item1","item2","item3"], function(n){
    var li = document.createElement ( 'li' );
    li.innerHTML = n;
    ul.appendChild ( li );
    return li;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I discovered an excellent example of [.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) in a practical setting.

Given the question of **How to append options to a selectbox given this array (or another array):**

```
selectValues = { "1": "test 1", "2": "test 2" };
```

[this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16058846/870729) uses `.map`:

```
$("mySelect").append(
  $.map(selectValues, function(v,k) {
     return $("<option>").val(k).text(v);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting code values to code text would be a possible use.  Such as when you have a select list and each indexed value has a corresponding code text.