# jQuery selector inquiry

Tags: jquery, selector

I need some hepl to find a selector for jQuery.

I have these textboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="text[1]" value="1,2,3">
<input type="text" name="text[2]" value="1,8,9">
<input type="text" name="text[3]" value="7,4,3">
```

I need for each these textboxes do a search and find if value=1 exist.

I need help to the selector (something like `$(input[name=text[]]).each()` )

I don't want to use `$(input[name^='text']).each()`, I don't think it's safe because the rest of my code. Is there a better way?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a parent element you could work with? e.g. if they're all in a div, you could do $("#container input[name^='text'").

Comment: i can create a container if needed.Never thought of that.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a placeholder class thus:

```
<input class="myselector" type="text" name="text[1]" value="1,2,3">
<input class="myselector" type="text" name="text[2]" value="1,8,9">
<input class="myselector" type="text" name="text[3]" value="7,4,3">
```

Then it's just a matter of:

```
$(input.myselector).each()
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in a container:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="text[1]" value="1,2,3">
    <input type="text" name="text[2]" value="1,8,9">
    <input type="text" name="text[3]" value="7,4,3">
</div>
```

And select them with it, like this.

```
$("#container > input").each(function(i, element){
    $element = $(element);
    if($element.val().indexOf('1') >= 0){
        $element.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
});
```

Or even write a custom selector like this:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    contains1: function(e) {
        return $(e).val().indexOf('1') >= 0; 
    }
});

$("#container > input:contains1").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: I like the customer selector example... +1

Comment: Yeah, custom selector are pretty slick. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks for more tips and tricks

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
$('input[name="^text["]').filter('[name$="]"]')
```

I don't know if you'll be able to make it any more specific than that with out using a function for the filter.  I'd probably be ok with the just name starts with text and make sure to use different ids elsewhere.

Comment: Thank.I have not use filter before.So i will test drive it

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` with something like:

```
$("input[type=text]").map(function() {if ($(this).val() == 1) return $(this)})
```