# Getting elements that exceed the maxium value. JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

Tags: jquery, get, find, width, element

greetings,

I'm new with java script so bear with me!
I want to achieve something using `JQuery` selectors.

I have a list menu. It looks like this...

```
<ul style="width:auto">
<li>item one</li>
<li>item two</li>
<li>item three</li>
<li>item four</li>
<li>item five</li>
</ul>
```

Okay, so currently I'm using the `parseInt` function to retrieve the integer value of the current width of the `ul`.

```
var ul = $("ul");
var currentWidth = parseInt(ul.width);
var maxWidth = 400;
```

With that giving me the current width I'd like to now create an if statement.
This is where it gets really tricky for me.

```
if(currentWidth <= maxWidth){
alert('great job, do nothing');
}
else {
  // WHAT DO I DO?!
  // I need to take all the elements that makes the ul exceed that maxWidth variable and assign them to a new array called extraItems
}
```

So how do I get those items. I fear this is so far beyond the basic!

Any help would be so greatly appreciated!

Objective example image: [imageShack link](http://img115.imageshack.us/img115/5856/examplef.jpg)

Comment: Just a tip, when using parseInt, you should always include the second argument, so in your case, use parseInt(ul.width,10) to ensure it uses base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would deal with it:

```
// given these values:
var ul = $("ul");
var maxWidth = 200;

// the total width counter
var acc = 0;  

// find the li's and use the map (or filter) function to filter away unwanted elements
var overflow = ul.find('li').map(function(){

  // add current elm's width to our total
  acc += $(this).outerWidth();

  // within bounds - return nothing
  if ( acc < maxWidth ) {
    return null;
  }
  // limit reached - return element
  else {
    return this;
  }

});

// we are left with only the "overflow" elements...
overflow.hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
else {
   var extraItems = [];
   $('ul li').each(function(i, e) {
      if ($(e).width() > maxWidth) {
         $(e).remove(); //? dunno if you want to remove em, but here's how
         extraItems.push(e);
      }
   });
   ...
}
```

Comment: he array returns null/empty

If I am reading your bit correctly you are doing "if the list item is greater than the max width of the ul then remove it and place it in the array"

This logic is correct however it pertains to a single list item that exceeds maxWidth.

The example above refers to a list that has a width 400 and all the list items combined are 500. Take each list item that went over the maximum and place it into the array. So, if the 3 first items are all together equal to 440 and adding one more to that giving us 520 then that last item should be sent to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/382922#382922) post by Andreas Grech... you can make your own selector to do this as well.

Edit: Oh and after reading what your ultimate goal is (hiding the overflow) why not just use the CSS class `overflow:hidden` on your content wrapper, then use a plugin like [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to move it around?

Edit #2 LOL sorry for editing so much... if you are just doing this to learn, try this code (I also have it running in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.me/f906856641336858de14f6e1fbd3d35f)), also make sure you look at the CSS, the `li` by default will have 100% width:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var ul = $("ul");
 var currentWidth = ul.width();
 var maxWidth = 400;
 if(currentWidth <= maxWidth){
  alert('great job, do nothing');
 } else {
  var liWidth = 0;
  var done = false;
  ul.find('li').each(function(indx){
   liWidth += $(this).width();
   if (liWidth > maxWidth && !done){
    ul.find('li:gt(' + (indx-1) + ')').hide();
    var done = true;
   }
  })
 }
 var savedLi = ul.find('li:hidden');
 alert( savedLi.length + ' elements were hidden');
})
```