# Changing the dimensions of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I want to change many elements (figcaption) dimensions to img dimensions with jquery
plz help me

```
var width = $("div[caption='true'] img").attr("width");

var height = $("div[caption='true'] img").attr("height");

$("div[caption='true'] figcaption").css("width",width);
$("div[caption='true'] figcaption").css("height",height);
```

**[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8ge1wvpt/8/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is setting each `figcaption`'s height and width to that of the first image. Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("div[caption='true']").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var width = $("img", $this).attr("width");
        var height = $("img", $this).attr("height");
        $("figcaption", $this).css({"height":height, "width":width});
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8ge1wvpt/9/)

Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
 
 
    $("div[caption='true']").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var width = $("img", $this).attr("width");
        var height = $("img", $this).attr("height");
        $("figcaption", $this).css({"height":height, "width":width});
    });
 
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.imgs{position:relative;}
figcaption{position:absolute;top:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
figcaption h3{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgs" caption="true">
  
   <img src="http://goo.gl/uRvjRS" width="200" height="250" alt=""/>
   <figcaption>
    <h3>IMGs Caption 1</h3>
   </figcaption>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="imgs" caption="true">
  
   <img src="http://goo.gl/uRvjRS" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
   <figcaption>
    <h3>IMGs Caption 2</h3>
   </figcaption>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="imgs" caption="true">
  
   <img src="http://goo.gl/uRvjRS" width="300" height="200" alt=""/>
   <figcaption>
    <h3>IMGs Caption 3</h3>
   </figcaption>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but could you explain what $this do exactly?

Comment: You are cacheing the `$(this)` object. It's a method of code optimisation. Not entirely necessary. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865965/does-jquery-this-need-to-be-cached

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("div[caption='true']").each(function() {
        var $this  = $(this);
        var image  = $this.find('img')
        var width  = image.width();
        var height = image.height();

        $this.find('figcaption').width(width).height(height);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ge1wvpt/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a function to fill in the css value:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("img + figcaption")
    .css("width",function() { return $(this).prev().attr("width");})
    .css("height",function() { return $(this).prev().attr("height"); });
});
```

This will match any `<img>` followed by `<figcaption>` - there is no need for the caption="true" attribute, unless you are using it for something else.