# is there anyway to make an iframe containg an embedded vimeo video silent?

Tags: html, css, iframe, video, vimeo

Hello is there a way to make my vimeo video below silent by adding properties to the iframe? if so could somebody please show me how?

```
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/77693293?api=1;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Looking at the staff responses on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865965/does-jquery-this-need-to-be-cached) it doesn't look like this feature will be coming any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know iframe solution 
See SWFObject + moogaloop solution 
Warning not work on desktop - install on your web server :
For more SWFObject documentation visit: code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

```
<div id="myvideo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function vimeo_player_loaded() {
moogaloop3 = document.getElementById('myvideo');
moogaloop3.api_setVolume(0);
}
var flashvars = {
'clip_id': '77693293',
'server': 'vimeo.com',
'show_title': 0,
'show_byline': 0,
'show_portrait': 0,
'fullscreen': 0,
'autoplay': 1,
'js_api': 1,
'js_onload': 'vimeo_player_loaded'
}
var parObj = {
'swliveconnect':true,
'fullscreen': 1,
'allowscriptaccess': 'always',
'allowfullscreen':true
};
var attObj = {}
attObj.id="myvideo";
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf", "myvideo", "500", "281", "9.0.0", '',flashvars,parObj, attObj );
</script>
```