# jQuery: passing $(this) to named function event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I note that it's recommended to [use named functions when binding an event handler to a javascript event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/696385#696385). How can I do this when my function needs to be passed the `this` object?

For example, how would I replace the anonymous function below by directly calling `doFancyStuff`:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', function () {
    doFancyStuff($(this));
});

function doFancyStuff($textbox) {
    // fanciness
}
```

Extra points if you point out other conventions I might be breaking with the above code.

---

To clarify, I want to call the `doFancyStuff()` method in my example from multiple places, otherwise yes, I could just do something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', doFancyStuff);

function doFancyStuff() {
    var $textbox = $(this);

    // fanciness
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say that's a matter of opinion.  I see no problem using an anonymous function here.  If this is the only place `doFancyStuff` is called, you could do this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', doFancyStuff);

function doFancyStuff() {
    // fanciness
    var $textbox = $(this)
}
```

However, if this function is called from multiple places and you can't change the way it works, you would have to do something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', doFancyStuffFromEvent);

function doFancyStuffFromEvent() {
    // fanciness
    doFancyStuff($(this));
}

function doFancyStuff($textbox) {
    // fanciness
}
```

Which is messy.

Comment: Unfortunately the function is called from multiple places - some places where `this` is not the the `$textbox` I want the function to have access to. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could change the function to suit what I need better?

Comment: The 2nd example is the way around this, though I prefer the code you started with that has the anonymous function.  Additionally, you could probably use the first and check if the first argument is a jquery object or an event and work differently in each, again I find this messier than the inline function.

Comment: An example of the testing of the first argument to see what type it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/Rzsep/  but I'm not putting it in my answer because I don't like it.  Note the way I test if it is an event is probably a crappy way to test, but it's just quick and dirty.

Answer (score 10):

I use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to solve this issue:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', $.proxy(doFancyStuff, myChoiceofThis);

function doFancyStuff(event) {

    // $el is the same as $(this) when using anonymous functions
    var $el = $(event.currentTarget); 

    // me === myChoiceOfThis 
    var me = this; // me === myChoiceOfThis
}
```

If `doFancyStuff`is an object method, then being able to give a reference such as `myChoiceOfThis` is very useful.

Comment: This is a very neat way to do it. You can execute an event handler in the context of any element you pass into the proxy.
`var proxy = $.proxy(doFancyStuff, $('.my-other-element'));`
`proxy();`

Comment: very nice answer! best and easiest way to do it!

Answer (score 7):

Just pass the function as is:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', doFancyStuff);

function doFancyStuff() {
    $(this).fancy(); // :-P
}
```

jQuery will automatically invoke your function with the proper context set.

---

As for `other conventions you might be breaking`: are you sure you need event delegation? If not, this would be much better:

```
$('input.fancy-textbox').on('change', doFancyStuff);
```

or you could even use the short-hand version:

```
$('input.fancy-textbox').change(doFancyStuff);
```

Comment: I do need event delegation in this case, but good point for others looking at this question

Answer (score 4):

You will actually be able to use `$(this)` inside your method `doFancyStuff` if you define it as your event handler. The .on() method will set the context (this) accordingly:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', doFancyStuff);

function doFancyStuff() {
    // 'this' will be the changed input.fancy-textbox
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `doFancyStuff` to expect the same signature as your anonymous function. The way you've coded this, it looks like it expects a single parameter of a jQuery object, and ignores "this."  But the parameter of an event is something else (the event object) and "this" is the target. If you want to use a function as an event target, then it's got to expect the same data. So rewrite:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.fancy-textbox', doFancyStuff);

function doFancyStuff(e) {
    var $textbox = $(this);       
    // fanciness
}
```