# Can we use any other symbol instead of jQuery and $ symbol in jquery

Tags: jquery

I was searching for the answer ,is it possible to have any other symbol instead of $ and Jquery in jquery program

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Tips and Tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks) look at the answer by Oli: [The noConflict function - Freeing up the $ variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/182666)

Answer (score 3):

**[jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)**.

In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.

```
var newJ = jQuery.noConflict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by Calling `noConflict()`

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp)

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
```

Comment: can we use @ like

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery.noConflict. 
Refer [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) for more details

Answer (score -2):

Modify below in your jquery.js file

```
$j=$;
```

to

```
$abcd=$; // some symbol you want
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, It's always better that we use `jQuery.noConflict()` function.